# Photo Pop out or Stand out in front of background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-draw, art

could someone tell me how I would make a photo standout or popout in front of a background, I have corel x3 and adobe photoshop 5.0

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add a screenshot of your not so good results, give a detailed explanation what is wrong and maybe another screenshot (no links!) what is a good one in the explained terms. Do it before your question is voted out or closed directly as unclear by some high rank member.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quess: You need a "Drop Shadow".

It creates the illusion which you probably want. An object or image seems to hover over the background.

An example in Photoshop:

[image]

Here a black, but blurred rectangle is added as a layer (=Shadow) between the flying object and the background.

That rectangle was actually a copy of the flying object, but turned to black with the levels control, shifted a little aside with the arrow tool and finally the opacity of the layer was reduced to make the shadow a little lighter.

The flying object has got a little contrast boost to make it different than the background.

Drop shadow is available in many programs as effect - no messing with blurring and extra layers. In Photoshop it's available as a layer style (= add the drop shadow to a layer).

*Important:* Several objects appear to have different hovering altitudes if they have different drop shadows. The apparent distance depends also on

- contrast
- color saturation
- zooming (if there's something to compare)

There's surely at least a hundred tutorials available. Search for Drop Shadow!